# Azure bot App settings: AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-bot-service

Where to find App settings in Azure bot, which was previously migrated from Microsoft bot framework? I want to set variable `AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage` with value of `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experence on Microsoft bot framework. But if you want to configurate the [Azure bot App settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-manage-overview#app-service-settings). You could find it on the Azure portal,more detail information please refer to the screenshot.

[image]